# Installing Ubuntu 18 from bootable USB won't let me install on SSD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, uefi

I have a new Dell XPS-15 9570 with Windows 10 home installed.  I want to install Ubuntu 18 as the host OS (not a dual boot) on the SSD.  I have a Ubuntu 18 bootable USB that I've used before to install Ubuntu 18 on an older desktop successfully.

I boot from the USB (press F12 during start up) and select Install Ubuntu.  The Ubuntu desktop is displayed with a Install Ubuntu icon.  I double click on this and the installation starts.  When the process gets to where I partition storage the only device displayed is /dev/sda which is the bootable USB memory stick.  The displayed text is "device for boot loader installation".  The Ubuntu installer doesn't recognize the SSD where I want to install it.

Is this the UEFI BIOS on the new laptop preventing me from installing Ubuntu on the SSD?  If so what do I have to do to install Ubuntu on the SSD.  (I want to reformat the SSD as part of the Ubuntu installation.)

Comment: Is the SSD MBR or GPT?  If it's unallocated then it should be detected in both Legacy and UEFI mode.

Comment: You probably need to reformat the SSD.

Answer (score 1):

I had to create a new bootable USB stick with Ubuntu 18.04.2. Version 18.04 didn't work. This seems to be the biggest factor.

The bios settings that had to be changed:

SATA: AHCI

POST FastBoot: Minimal

Ubuntu 18.04.2 seems to work fine with secure boot.  More discussion can be found [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2413124&p=13839483#post13839483).